# Контейнер deque в STL c++

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, библиотеки, контейнеры

Я начал изучения библиотеки STL и нашел такой интересный контейнер, как `deque`, но я не понял, в чем его преимущество, если можно заменить его другими контейнерами из того же STL?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

А чем вообще один контейнер отличается от другого? И вообще, все их можно заменить обычным массивом...

В конце концов, какая разница, искать ли элемент в контейнере час или пару секунд, или - ну что тут такого страшного, если вставка в начало массива требует перемещения всех его элементов?

Или это существенно?

Тогда учтите, что дек обеспечивает быструю вставку-удаление с обоих концов контейнера - чего, например, не может обеспечить `vector`, но при этом быстрое (хотя чуть медленнее, чем у `vector`) обращение к любому элементу внутри, чего, например, не может обеспечить `list`. Но при этом он не может обеспечить быстрый поиск, как у `set` или `unordered_set`...

Ну, а чтобы вам было легче выбирать, какой именно контейнер вам нужен - вот неплохая шпаргалка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще одна сводная шпаргалка по функциям контейнеров:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]