# Удаление элемента массива без смещения C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Задача в том, чтобы удалять элементы массива по индексу. Но делать это нужно без смещения элементов(a[n] = a[n+1]), ибо много времени на эти операции уходит. Использую динамическое выделение памяти через malloc. 
Использование массива не принципиально, можно и свое что-то сделать, главное эффективное по памяти и времени.

Comment: Эээ... А что должно быть на месте удалённых элементов, если сдвига не делать? Если ответ «что угодно», то вам не нужна никакая операция, просто считайте элемент с индексом `n` отсутствующим и не обращайтесь к нему.

Comment: А при обращении на чтение к этому элементу что должно быть возвращено? Следующий?

Comment: Если серьёзно, то нет, массив/vector — это структуры данных с медленным удалением. Быстрое удаление есть у `unordered_set`, например. Какие вам нужны операции с вашей структурой данных?

Comment: задача в том, что существует массив(или не массив) из 10 элементов. Программа должна представлять собой считалочку по кругу. Т.е. выбывает каждый 3-й(например). Вылетают номера 3, 6, 9, 2, 7 и т.д.

Comment: придумал, как реализовать без использования массива)

Comment: А длина круга уменьшается при удалении элемента?

Comment: Естественно, в этом вся соль :)

Comment: Тогда используйте не массив, а связный список. И да, на 10 элементов смещение элементов массива занимает несколько наносекунд, по сравнению со вводом-выводом это ничтожно малая величина.

Comment: А элементы как-то идентифицированы? То есть им присвоены первоначальные значения 1, 2, 3... ? Или при удалении производится переидентификация? Тогда это у вас будет удаление не 3, 6, 9, а 3, 7 (которая переместилась в 6), 11 (которая переместилась в 9). Так-то можно зацикленный список сделать, но что с идентификацией элементов, не понятно.

Comment: Задача Иосифа? Посмотрите в википедию, там должны быть эффективные решения.

Comment: задача Иосифа Флавия, она, премного благодарен))

Comment: Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/708447/195342) есть шпаргалка по выбору соответствующего контейнера. Что касается задачи Иосифа Флавия, то она детально разобрана в *Конкретной математике* Грэхема-Кнута-Паташника, раздел 1.3.