# Где ошибся с функцией Insert?

Tags: c++, insert

Задача для этой части кода: Если получаемое число меньше первого в векторе, то нужно это число вставить на первое место в векторе, а остальное сдвинуть вправо(обычная вставка в отсортированный вектор).

```
if (a[0]>=b) {
a.insert(0, b);
}
```

Но выделяет точку перед insert с данной проблемой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же "insert" написать как "Insert", то будет выделение всего Insert с последующим описанием:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.
Вектор я создал так: `vector<int> a={1,4,8,10,10,39,50,86,110,1000000};`

Подключенные библиотеки:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include "vector"
```

Был бы рад, если мне объяснили бы ещё разницу между последовательными контейнерами, видимо vector не самый лучший выбор в данной ситуации

Comment: Итератор нужен в качестве первого аргумента. А вообще нехорошо использовать вектор для таких целей, лучше дек или лист

Comment: Дек или лист можете поподробней?

Comment: Описание insert для [вектора](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), для [дека](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/insert) и [листа](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert)

Comment: По поводу разных контейнеров рекомендую посмотреть этот вопрос -  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708404/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80-deque-%d0%b2-stl-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрим на описание [`vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) и видим, что первым идет *итератор*, перед которым нужно вставлять элемент, т.е. вставка должна делаться так:

```
a.insert(a.begin(), b);
```

По поводу разных контейнеров рекомендую посмотреть этот вопрос - [Контейнер deque в STL c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708404/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80-deque-%d0%b2-stl-c)