# Как максимально быстро удалить первые n элементов из листа?

Tags: c++, list, c++14

Есть `std::list<MyClass> list` с 10000+ элементов
Есть `int n = 500;` 
Нужно удалить первые `n` элементов.

---

Как сделать это максимально быстро?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase

Comment: @Harry это не совсем то. Если удалять поэлементно то это будет аналогично pop_front в цикле

Comment: В любом случае 1. *стандартный* способ только этот, 2. он не может быть быстрее O(n), потому что для каждого элемента следует вызвать деструктор. Можно разве что воспользоваться splice, а потом убить второй список...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал такой пример чтобы проверить возможность не удалять ненужные элементы, а создать список только с нужными элементами:

```
std::list<int> data;

for (int index = 0; index < 10000; index++)
    data.push_back(index);

__int64 t1;
::QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&t1);

std::list<int>::iterator range_end = data.begin();
std::advance(range_end, 500);

std::list<int> data2;
data2.insert(data2.begin(), range_end, data.end());

__int64 t2;
::QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&t2);

std::cout << (t2 - t1) << std::endl;
```

Промерил разные скорости

Ситуация такая:

до определённого кол-ва удаляемых элементов выгоднее удалять из списка элементы, после определённого кол-ва элементов - создавать новый список, а старый список удалять потом (если такая возможность есть)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но по большей части все может упираться в конструктор и деструктор вашего класса `MyClass`, так что работа со списком уже не будет иметь никакого существенного значения

P.S.

опять же вопрос - что именно вам нужно

если вам нужно часто создавать и удалять элементы списка, причем где-то посередине списка - тогда конечно `std::list` - это ваше,

если добавляются и удаляются элементы только в конце - тогда `std::vector` - это более оптимальное (и быстрое и памяти меньше кушает) решение

если удаление и добавление элементов происходит гораздо реже, чем получение значений элементов, тогда опять таки зачастую `std::vector` подходит гораздо лучше

P.P.S.

Но `splice` гораздо выгоднее `insert`, ГОРАЗДО ВЫГОДНЕЕ!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. специально показал логарифмическую шкалу, чтобы была понятна мощь `splice` :)

Comment: А попробовать не `insert`, а `splice`? он должен работать за константное время; `insert` все же данные копирует.

Comment: @Harry, добавил измерение в ответ - да, `splice` рвет!

Comment: Но это только если не удалять остатки :) Кстати, жаль, что автор не хочет поделиться, что именно за объекты в списке - можно было бы подумать и о других контейнерах.

Comment: Объект - класс, включающий int и указатель на вектор

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG Ага, т.е. просто POD - указатель же при удалении элемента освобождать не надо, надеюсь? А какие действия со списком предполагаются? Да, при ответе напишите, pls, @ и Harry одним словом - ну, чтобы я заметил, что мне отвечают, я ваш комментарий "никому" заметил чисто случайно...

Comment: А если добавить в каждый способ еще и удаление ненужного более списка, то как будут выглядеть кривульки?

Comment: @Mikhailo, а смотря как вы его хотите удалять - ведь если вы перепишете алокаторы, списки будут создаваться не просто как-то поэлементно, а строго в выделенной для этого вами памяти, то удаление будет мгновенным, потому что никак API ОС затрагивать не будет :) Опять же вопрос к частоте таких удалений/созданий - может всего делов то на мегабайт  или даже десяток мегабайт, тогда и до завершения программы можно подождать

Comment: @Harry туда добавляются в одном потоке данные, одновременно в других потоках они обрабатываются (поэтому и указатель на вектор), после записывается все в файл и удаляется. Но, т.к. ядер меньше кол-ва данных, то сперва обрабатываются первые 4 элемента, сохраняются и удаляются, затем следующие

Comment: Т.е. получается типичная очередь? тогда почему бы не испробовать `deque`? Как небольшая шпаргалка :) - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/708447/195342

Answer (score 2):

Стандартно - использовать [`erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase)

Как вариант - перенести ненужные элементы в другой список за константное время, который потом убить.

```
void kill(list<int>& l, size_t count)
{
    list<int> tmp;
    auto it = l.begin();
    advance(it,count);
    tmp.splice(tmp.begin(),l,l.begin(),it);
}
```

Что быстрее - надо сравнивать экспериментально...

Как показал [эксперимент](https://ideone.com/dkCAuc), обычный `erase` все же несколько быстрее.